# What is Laravel's CSRF Token Pattern?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, csrf

I want to know how Laravel:

1. creates **CSRF** tokens
2. where it is located
3. expiration time

When I refresh the web page I see the same token that was already created and how increase or decrease expiration time?

Answer (score 1):

In **laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Session/Store.php** there is a function called `regenerateToken()` ([github](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.5/src/Illuminate/Session/Store.php#L598))

```
/**
 * Regenerate the CSRF token value.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function regenerateToken()
{
    $this->put('_token', Str::random(40));
}
```

It just uses a 40 character long random string as you can see.